# Python Selenium is redirecting the URL to Sign up page

Tags: python, session, selenium

I have the following code:

```
> from selenium import webdriver
> browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =
 r"C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\chromedriver.exe")
> browser.get('http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first=jatin&last=wadhwa&trk=prof-samename-search-submit')
> print (browser.page_source)
```

What's happening is I want to open In spite of ->
 http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first=jatin&last=wadhwa&trk=prof-samename-search-submit

it is going ->

https://www.linkedin.com/start/join?session_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fpub%2Fdir%2F%3Ffirst%3Djatin%26last%3Dwadhwa%26trk%3Dprof-samename-search-submit&source=sentinel_org_block&trk=login_reg_redirect

Any solution so that it opens the desired link not the redirected one?

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin does not search page without login. First login on linkedin then you can scrape data.

```
browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/')
elem = browser.find_element_by_name('session_key')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(email_id) # enter your email id or phone number

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('session_password')
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(password) # enter your linkedin password

submit = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pagekey-uno-reg-guest-home"]/div[1]/div/form/input[6]')
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.click(submit)
actions.perform() # after this you will be login

# Now you can open url without redirecting

browser.get(`'http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first=jatin&last=wadhwa&trk=prof-samename-search-submit')`
```

Comment: I want to do this without logging in the linkedIn. If u go directly to this in browser it's working (without logging in):
http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first=jatin&last=wadhwa&trk=prof-samename-search-submit

Comment: I think you are login  in your browser. open your url in incognito mode and you will see it is redirecting to login page.

Comment: No. It's opening in incognito where i am not logged in.

Comment: That is exactly. what i want to say. when you use selenium, it open web page in incognito mode, and in incognito mode you are not logged in, so linkedin is redirecting you to login page.

Comment: What's the Solution? If I do a normal query in INCOGNITO for top profiles with the name "Jatin Wadhwa" it gives me results in first or second google results. That I am able to open without being redirected to sign up page.
Can you explain that?  how is that different from opening directly through URL?

Comment: The url you are opening is not public. you have to login on linkedin.

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin redirect you to the signup page if you are crawling too fast.

I recommend you to wait a random amount of time between each http request.

Deleting your cookies wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: I just made a single request.

Comment: sorry, i didn't check the url. If you want to scrape the private profiles, you need to be logged in as stated in the other answer.
if you want to scrape the public profiles,  use the following url:
https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/jatin/wadhwa?trk=uno-reg-guest-home-name-search

Comment: I want to scrape the public profile but the URL you provided is redirecting to login page even when i am opening it normally in incognito browser(without logging in with LinkedIn Credentials)